# Convert data.frame with type of list into a numeric dataframe I can run analyses on in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, numeric, qualtrics

When I imported a survey from Qualrics as a csv on my computer it was supposed to download it as numeric values. When I read the dataframe into R it's mode is "list".

I would like to keep my data in the same shape with the same column labels within it.

For example...

```
df1 <- structure(list(RSE1 = c("1", "1", "3"), RSE2 = c("1", 
"2", "3"), RSE3 = c("2", "1", "3"), RSE4 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE5 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE6 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE7 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE8 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE9 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE10 = c("2", "4", "2")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Most suggestions I see online say I should unlist it, but that creates a single column.
I tried...

```
surveyResps<-unlist(lapply(surveyResps, as.numeric))
```

and

```
surveyResps<-as.numeric(unlist(surveyResps))
```

then

```
as.numeric(surveyResps)
```

outputs

```
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Any suggestions? The two things I need to make sure are unchanged are the labels and the shape.

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: **Be advised**: `inherits(mtcars, "data.frame")` is true, but also `mode(mtcars)` returns `"list"`. A `data.frame` is a special kind of `list` (each column has the same length), but underneath it all it is still a `list`. If your columns are supposed to be numbers but are being read in as strings, then something is wrong either with the source data-document or the code that you are using to import the data.

Comment: Can you comment on how you're reading in your dataframe? `readr::read_csv(<filepath>, col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))` might take away the need to convert anything if your df is entirely numeric

Comment: ```survey<-read.csv("~/Downloads/survey.csv")``` and an example df is ```df1 <- structure(list(RSE1 = c("1", "1", "3"), RSE2 = c("1", 
"2", "3"), RSE3 = c("2", "1", "3"), RSE4 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE5 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE6 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE7 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE8 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE9 = c("2", "4", "2"), RSE10 = c("2", "4", "2")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))```

Comment: I'd suggest you try the `readr::read_csv` method I've used in the example in my comment above. It's more powerful than the base R `read.csv` you are currently working with. In this case it adds the value of being able to specify the type you want to read your columns as...

Comment: Thank you @alex_jwb90, this works; ```survey<-read_csv("~/Downloads/Learning_To_Code_Surveys.csv", col_names = T, col_types = cols(.default = col_integer()))
```

Comment: Does that also solve your parallel question where you had struggled with some warning on using `-` on factor data?

Comment: It did solve the parallel question as well.